Enter data in a specific cell in embedded Excel object using PowerPoint form
I have a PowerPoint slide with an embedded Excel object with link.
I am trying to enter data in a specific cell in the embedded Excel object using a PowerPoint VBA form.
Sub Populate_Excel_Obj()

 Dim obj As Object
 Dim wb As Excel.Workbook   'User defined type not defined !!!
 Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

 Set obj = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Object 21") 'Shape21 is the excel object in powerpony


 Set wb = obj.OLEFormat.Object
 Set ws = wb.Sheets("Cap Charging Calc")

 If (ws.Range("B2").Value <> "") Then
   ws.Range("B2").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Text
 End If

End Sub

I expected the Excel worksheet to be updated with the PowerPoint form text box info.

You've posted the code but haven't mentioned what happens when you run it, other than, apparently, a user type undefined error. That's because you haven't set a reference to the Excel object library.
